# Alternative to Get-WindowsFeature

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell-1.0

I need to list all Windows features on a Windows Server 2008.

On Windows Server 2008 **R2** the `Get-WindowsFeature` command is available after importing the module `ServerManager`. But on Windows Server 2008 it is not.

Does anyone know a good alternative to Get-WindowsFeature?

Comment: Found it: ServerManagerCmd.exe -query

Comment: great that you found it, but it's impressive how fast you found it yourself when you tried. please show the same effort before posting here =)

Comment: @Frode-f there is nothing wrong with sharing a bit of knowledge..

Comment: Of course, but it took less than 30mins before he found it. Too slow to be a "ask and answer"-post, but still fast enough to show that he didn't research enough before posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it: `ServerManagerCmd.exe -query`